# Unable to show that the graph is planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

How to show that the following graph is planar?

[image]

I tried to redraw the graph but I cant draw it without the edges crossing.

Also I find that the edges $3,4,5$ form a complete graph.
Also I am unable to find any subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.
So I am confused whether  it  is planar or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place vertices $5$ and $1$ inside triangle $234$.[image]
Graph with $5$ vertices can't be subdivision of $K_{3,3}$, and it can be subdivision of $K_5$ only if it's $K_5$ itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer +1!

Answer (score 2):

It is planar. See the attached image for a planar embedding.
[image: a planar embedding]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer +1!

Answer (score 1):

$K_{3, 3}$ requires at least 6 veritces, and $K_5$ would require that all five vertices you have are completely connected. This is not the case, so the graph is planar.

As for redrawing, here is one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer +1!